# cPickle underflow error

Tags: python, file-io, pickle

I'm trying to load a file using cPickle as follows,

```
import cPickle

cPickle.load(open('test', 'rb'))
```

However, I get this error,

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnpicklingError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-527-1b7653ff1917> in <module>()
----> 1 cPickle.load(open('test', 'rb'))

UnpicklingError: unpickling stack underflow
```

And sometimes it gives out this error

```
UnpicklingError: could not find MARK
```

Any reason why I'm getting this?

PS: cPickle is not working with me with any file, even newly created files containing only two words. I am using ubuntu 12.04 and Python 64bit

Comment: Looks like you might be missing some leading or trailing bytes. How did you make the file? Did you flush before closing it? Is it small enough to post here?

Comment: @dan.lecocq, I have updated the question, basically, its not working with any file, the file contents is something like "test test", I create my files by right-clicking on file creation

Comment: Could you post the output of: `cPickle.loads(cPickle.dumps("test"))`?

Comment: Yes, <code> In [544]: cPickle.loads(cPickle.dumps("test"))
Out[544]: 'test' </code>

Comment: Ok. Well at least your `cPickle` module's relatively sane :-). When you say that your file contents is something like "test test", are you making this file by hand? They have to be made by `cPickle` to be read by `cPickle`. Short of that, I'd try writing it out to a file, and verifying that it matches `cPickle.dumps('test')`. If you hop on SO chat, we can do a little more interactive debugging.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! Got it working! I saved a file with cPickle, that I got it load properly !

Answer (score -1):

Try this it fixed the error for me:

```
import pickle
import pandas as pd


# read in csv file to pandas dataframe and save as pickle file
training_data = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
pickle_out = open('train.pkl', 'wb')
pickle.dump(training_data, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close() 


# open pickle file
file = 'train.pkl'
with open(file, 'rb') as f:
    training_data = pickle.load(f)
```